# JavaScript input validation with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I want to validate my inputs, so the user can just enter letters. The problem is that it just checks one input field but I selected all with `:input`

code:

```
$('#formularID').submit(function() {
   var allInputs = $(":input").val();
   var regex     = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]");
   if(regex.test(allInputs))
   {
       alert("true");
   }else
   {
       alert("false");
       return false;
   }
});
```

I appreciate every help I can get!

Comment: When you want to test a whole string, you must describe a whole string (and not only one character). But you can do it in another way, if you build a pattern that must not match the subject (for example using a negated character class with forbidden characters). In this case, you only need to test if the pattern fails and one character suffices.

Comment: Use the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to cycle through each input element, you are only getting/testing the value of the first one by doing `$(":input").val()`.

Comment: thanks for the fast replies! @Casimir et Hippolyte - You're right, I used `!` and just checked whether the pattern fails. And @Spencer Wieczorek - (I don't know whether I can do that ) I used `$(":input").val().each()` but then he does just submit the form without checking the value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly you need to cycle through each of your input elements, you can do this by using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
// Cycles through each input element
$(":input").each(function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    ...
});
```

Next your RegExp is only checking for the first character to be a letter, if you want to ensure that only a steam of letters can match you will want to use `^[a-zA-Z]+$` instead:

```
$(":input").each(function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    if(regex.test(input)) {
        alert("true");
    }else {
        alert("false");
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**Here is an example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7d7t6wud/)

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Finally he does check all my inputs!