# how auto edit works on textfield on webpage

Tags: javascript, html

i am building a [website](http://uecu.ac.in/Index.aspx) that should not allow entering the characters '@#$% into its text fields.

Can any one help me figure out that how to do that using JavaScript.

Comment: here is the website http://uecu.ac.in/Index.aspx

Comment: Hi John! Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be really great if you could let us know what effort you did to try to accomplish that.

Comment: i just opened the source files and searched for and code patch that had [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: @mohhamad hasham and to change it to [!-/a-zA-Z0-9], this might work , but i don't know were to find it

Comment: These are regex expressions, you can read more on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript input validation with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534411/javascript-input-validation-with-regex)

Comment: If HTML5 is used then [`pattern` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to validate the input using regular expressions. However, client side validation is not secure itself, you will need to validate on the server the input too, if you want users to not bypass (willingly or not) the check.
For example, users could have javascript disabled, or use a browser which stopped executing javascript scripts after an error (the submit in the FORM element will continue to happen, javascript will not).

an easy regex to accept only digits and letters is `/[a-zA-z0-9]+/`

some documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

to play with it:

https://regex101.com/